# Jmeter - Cannot sessionId when passing in Body data

Tags: json, jmeter, sessionid

Http request 1 - Get

Extracted the sessionId using Regular Expression Extractor and then passing the reference variable to another request through body data

```
{
"sessionId":"${sesid}"
}
```

Through a response as 400 bad request.

But, if i passed it in Parameters or Url path it fetches the sessionId. But it throws an error only for body data.

Please help me how to resolve this

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking.

Comment: I am trying to call an api and passing the api parameters through bodydata but its showing 400 error. but through parameter it is working.I am using Jmeter 3.1

Comment: add the screenshots for both working and error conditions to the question. Add View Results Tree to check.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use this as? 
    {
    "sessionId":${sesid}
    }